# Import citation data for BibTeX using DOI?

Tags: web-access, citation-management

I recently discovered that [Digital Object Identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier) can be used for a lot more than just a reliable link to an article or dataset, and in some cases the DOI url's support semantic queries.

[This article](http://www.crossref.org/CrossTech/2011/04/content_negotiation_for_crossr.html) details an approach to access meta data and content from a DOI using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), a command line tool and library. How can I access this data using Mathematica's functionality?

WRI has also been working to include [citation management](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CitationManagement.html#100648331) tools in the front-end. Is there already something like this built-in to deal with DOI's?

Comment: Related question: [Operations via public url access](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/504/operations-on-online-files-via-public-url-access).

Answer (score 8):

Using `URLFetch` with a specific header "text/bibliography" should return BibTeX citation data:

```
URLFetch["http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-10892-1_3", 
 "Headers" -> {"Accept" -> "text/bibliography"}]
```

By default in my Mathematica notebook, this displays in the following format:

> Erdos, P. (2011). Some Problems On The Distribution Of Prime Numbers.
>   Teoria Dei Numeri, 79â88. doi:10.1007/978-3-642-10892-1_3