# Managing citations reliably, especially using BibTex (from e.g. Zotero)

Tags: citation-management

I am using MMA 10.1 on Win 7 64-bit. I have read various questions lamenting poor/non-existent citation capabilities in MMA.

My experience is that I was able, once, to get some BibTeX citations out of Zotero and into Mathematica using plain BibTeX export.

However, having just exported a new BibTeX file, on trying to add a new citation all previous citations were lost (though the citation references [n] remain) - and the new citation didn't appear either.

I tried using an EndNote formatted export as well, but that couldn't even be read (Does it need the EndNote dll? If so, why - it's XML!)

Question: is there any known combination of formats (e.g. BibTeX, Better BibTeX, etc.), procedures, constraints (e.g. reference only 1 file) that will **reliably** allow citations to be imported, managed etc.?

How does anybody else manage?

(NB the Citation error 1792 or whatever also crops up and has been reported)

As Requested - Minimal Example(s) and further info. 
(Indented bibfile lines begin with tabs.

Bib file 1

```
    @article{schmidt_new_1997,
    title = {A new proof of {Birkhoff}'s theorem},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9709071},
    urldate = {2014-01-06},
    journal = {arXiv preprint gr-qc/9709071},
    author = {Schmidt, H.-J.},
    year = {1997}
}
```

Bib file 2

```
@article{uneyama_fluctuation_2015,
    title = {Fluctuation analysis of time-averaged mean-square displacement for the {Langevin} equation with time-dependent and fluctuating diffusivity},
    volume = {92},
    url = {http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.92.032140},
    number = {3},
    urldate = {2016-09-28},
    journal = {Physical Review E},
    author = {Uneyama, Takashi and Miyaguchi, Tomoshige and Akimoto, Takuma},
    year = {2015},
    pages = {032140},
    file = {1411.5165v3.pdf:D\:\\User Julian\\Documents\\Bibtex\\Zotero\\storage\\9X8G6FWP\\1411.5165v3.pdf:application/pdf}
}

@article{schmidt_new_1997,
    title = {A new proof of {Birkhoff}'s theorem},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9709071},
    urldate = {2014-01-06},
    journal = {arXiv preprint gr-qc/9709071},
    author = {Schmidt, H.-J.},
    year = {1997},
    file = {A new proof of Birkhoff’s theorem (Schmidt, 1997) (9709071v1.pdf:D\:\\User Julian\\Documents\\Bibtex\\Zotero\\storage\\S62IV3MV\\A new proof of Birkhoff’s theorem (Schmidt, 1997) (9709071v1.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

Open new notebook; make text cell; insert citation, use bibtex and refer to file 1. Insert the only item. It works.

Create second text cell; insert citation using second bibtex file. 2nd citation appears but 1st disappears, and new citation is numbered 1.

Issue unresolved by rebuidling bibliography.

Use of 2nd bibtex file causes error

```
INTERNAL SELF-TEST ERROR: EndNoteUtil|c|1782
Click here to find out if this problem is known, and to help improve
the Wolfram System by reporting it to Wolfram Research.
```

It would seem that the "file" parameter may cause the error, but does that having anything to do with the corruption of the bibliography?

Further info

This bibtex entry (saved as a single file) is read by citation, but as soon as search is clicked for "Boyd" the dialog list is replaced with a MMA formual grid[...] and error message as shown below

```
@misc{john_r._boyd_destruction_1976,
    title = {Destruction \& {Creation}},
    url = {http://danford.net/boyd/destruction.htm},
    author = {{John R. Boyd}},
    month = sep,
    year = {1976},
    file = {Destruction & Creation (John Boyd).pdf:D\:\\User Julian\\Documents\\Bibtex\\Zotero\\storage\\Z3FXM2D5\\Destruction & Creation (John Boyd).pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should try to set up a specific minimal example of what you need and what you've tried so the users here can help you.

Comment: Related: [citation management](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CitationManagement.html) and [76409](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76409/import-citation-data-for-bibtex-using-doi).

Comment: @dionys Info added, but I wasn't asking for help in fixing e.g. a formula or such like, I was asking what worked _reliably_ for others. Maybe such questions belong elsewhere, but now there's more data it can go either way.

Comment: Although I use MMA a lot, I use [JabRef](https://www.jabref.org/). Its a dedicated reference manager that handles pretty much all citation formats.   It runs on a Java Virtual Machine, so is Linux, Windows & OS friendly.  It can 'paste citations into' text editors including the one I use, Emacs.