# What is the smart way to insert references?

Tags: reference-request

I am using mathematica 12.1  I have tried to insert bibliographical references in every way possible, using endnote and bibtex files extracted from a wide array of programs to no avail. My question is, how can I insert references?

Comment: It depends on what do you want to achieve. You want that the reference does what? Updates as soon as you move (exchange) parts of the text? Pops up as soon as you hover the cursor over it? Opens in a new window as soon as you click on it? Or your question is about the suitable software to use when you need to insert the reference? Please also specify with what StyleSheet are you going to use references? It is intended for you, or external readers? If the latter, will they read this as a notebook, cdf or pdf?

Comment: I am using the default stylesheet with the aim of saving the document in pdf for external readers. What I want to achieve is to have a bibliography at the end of the document based on the paper I cite in the body of the paper. I have in mind something akin to \cite{.} in latex. I gather that what I wanted to do is intended to be straightforward by going to Insert/Citation. However my problem is that I didn't manage to import an external bibliography no matter how hard I tried. So I guess that the choice of software/bibtex file matters for the question at hand.

Comment: Related: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127402/managing-citations-reliably-especially-using-bibtex-from-e-g-zotero) | [2](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CitationManagement.html) | [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76409/import-citation-data-for-bibtex-using-doi)

Comment: I looked into this question several years ago. At that time Mma had a mechanism to insert references from the database, but it did not work. I am not aware of the present status.  A good workaround for that I described [here][1]. There it is described for referencing formulas and images, but exactly the same approach works for references. If the application of the method will seem unclear, let me know. Last, I recommend you to use the JournalArticle StyleSheet for such purposes. 
[1]: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18206/mathematica-equation-tagging/18219#18219